# Is there a second-order expression of '$\kappa$ is Reinhardt' in $NGB$, where $\kappa$ is a cardinal?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals

In their paper, "Generalizations of the Kunen inconsistency", (*Annals of Pure and Applied Logic* **163** (2012) 1872-1890, doi:[10.1016/j.apal.2012.06.001](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.apal.2012.06.001), arXiv:[1106.1951](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.1951)), Hamkins, Kirmayer, and Perlmutter write the following (pg. 1888—I quote Theorem 32, Corollary 34(1), and their commentary on the proofs of the theorem and the corollary preceding Theorem 32):

> Theorem 32.  Assume only $ZF$ [*Corollary 34(1) is the $NGB$ version of this ( see pg. 1874)--my comment*] There is no nontrivial elementary embedding $j$:  $V$ $\rightarrow$ $V$ that is definable from parameters.
>
> Corollary 34.  Do not assume $AC$.  For any transitive class $M$, there is no nontrivial elementary embedding $j$:  $M$ $\rightarrow$ $V$, with a critical point, that is definable from parameters in $V$.
>
> The essence of the proof is the classical observation that the concept of being a Reinhardt cardinal, if consistent, cannot be first order expressible, since if $\kappa$ is the least Reinhardt cardinal, witnessed by $j$: $V$ $\rightarrow$ $V$, then by elementarity $j$($\kappa$) would also be the least Reinhardt cardinal, contrary to $\kappa$ $\lt$ $j$($\kappa$).  Indeed, for the same reason, there can be no consistent first-order property $\varphi$($\kappa$) implying that that $\kappa$ is Reinhardt?

also this, from the paragraph below the proof of Theorem 32:

> The proof of Theorem 32 worked by observing that if $j$: $V$ $\rightarrow$ $V$ is definable in $V$, even with parameters, then the concept of being Reinhardt with respect to that definition for some parameter is first order expressible [*this seems to imply that there are two tiers of functions in $NGB$--one tier for sets and one tier for proper classes (following Bernays' two separate membership relations-- $\in_{set}$ for sets and $\in_{class}$ for classes?)--my comment*].

Question:  What is the second-order formula that expresses for some cardinal $\kappa$, that "$\kappa$ is a Reinhardt cardinal", and is that second-order formula expressible in $NBG$?

Finally (just to note), I am using the Hamkins, Kirmayer, Prelmutter understanding of $NGB$ ( i.e., $NGB$ without Choice or Global Choice).  Others, (such as Yurii Khomskii, in his slide presentation, "Alternative set theories" ([pdf](https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/khomskii/ALST/slides.pdf))) hold that Global Choice is a class axiom of $NGB$ (on the other hand, Khomskii holds that Replacement is a set axiom—does that mean that Replacement does not hold for proper classes in $NGB$?)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: The answer is essentially contained in "Generalizations of the Kunen Inconsistency" starting at the last paragraph of page 5 and continuing until the end of the metamathematical preliminaries.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg:  Page 5?  In the version published in _Annals of Pure and Applied Logic_, the quote that got rid of the downvote was on the third page of the published version.  Are you referring to page 5 in some preprint version of the paper?  If so, then could you supply a link to the preprint in question?  I would be much obliged if you would. Thanks.   I am also interested in what would happen if one added the Wholeness axiom as a class axiom of $NGB$ ($NGBC$ as well).  Because "$NGB$ includes the replacement...axiom only for formulas having only first-order quantifiers, that is,

Comment: (cont.) quantifying only over sets, allowing finitely many class parameters" (this is also on the third page of the published version), it may be able to escape the fact that in ($ZFC$, $j$), the wholeness axiom is below $I_{3)$ in consistency strength because ($ZFC$, $j$) is not a class theory..

Comment: I'm referring to the preprint on arXiv, which you linked to in the question. The only problem in formulating the axiom is to assert that a class $j$ is an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$, since it seems to require a truth predicate. Once you know the trick for doing this, you just say "there is a class $j$ that is an elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$." The trick is explained in great detail in "Generalizations of the Kunen Inconsistency."

Comment: @GabeGoldberg:  The arXiv preprint link was part of David Robert's fine edit (thanks, Prof. Roberts).  Thanks for pointing it out as well, Prof. Goldberg.  The trick is, I presume, is to use Gaifman's Lemma (Lemma 2 in both papers) to show that "a class $j$ from $V$ to $V$ that is an elementary embedding is a fully elementary embedding?  Can one then use Gaifman's Lemma to show the following relative consistency results:  "If  $Con$($NGB$) then $Con$($NGB$ + $WA_{\infty}$)", "If $Con$($NGBC$)  then $Con$($NGBC$+ $WA_{\infty}$)"?

Comment: What's $\text{WA}_\infty$?

Comment: @GabeGoldberg:  It is the Wholeness Axiom holding for the full Separation axiom in the language {$\in$, $j$} [which is an intermediate subtheory of $NGB$ = $AC$--my comment].  See Prof Hamkins' paper "The Wholeness axioms and $V$ = $HOD$", arXiv:math/9902079v1 [math.LO] 13 Feb 1999.

Comment: I don't see why the statement of the Wholeness Axiom, when formulated in second order set theory, is any different from the statement that there is a Reinhardt cardinal... NBG proves that for all classes $C$, the first-order replacement schema holds relative to $C$.

Comment: @GabeGoldberg:  It isn't any different.  The beauty of having $WA_{\infty}$ as a class axiom in $NGB$ (or in $NGB$ + $AC$ or in $NGBC$--the previous comment in square brackets should read, "[through which $ZFC$($j$) is an intermediate subtheory of $NGB$ +$AC$--my comment]") is that $NGB$, $NGB$ + $AC$, and $NGBC$ treats $j$ as a proper class (that way it is not weakly definable in $V$) and so avoids the problem of why $ZFC$ + $I_3$ is of greater consistency strength than $ZFC$ + $WA_{\infty}$.  As regards your comment, "$NGB$ proves that for all classes $C$, the first-order replacement schema

Comment: (cont.) holds relative to $C$", consider the following formulation of the Wholeness axiom, "There is a nontrivial elementary embedding $j$:  $V$ $\rightarrow$ $V$ that is not weakly definable in $V$, such that for all sets $A$, $j$ $\upharpoonright$ $A$ is a set" (it should be understood that this axiom holds for the full Separation axiom and that treating $WA_{\infty}$ as a class axiom in $NGB$, $NGB$ + $AC$, and $NGBC$ causes each of the three theories to treat $j$ as a proper class).  Given this formulation (and its proper understanding), how does the the fact that $NGB$, $NGB$ + $AC$,

Comment: (cont.) all imply "that for all classes $C$, the first-order replacement schema holds relative to $C$" have any relavence for $j$ when $WA_{\infty}$ is a class axiom of any of the three theories, except to show "that for all sets $A$, $j$ $\upharpoonright$ $A$ is a set"?

Comment: For reference, I have decided to include the definition of 'weakly definable' (the definition is essentially footnote 6 on pg. 246 of Corazza's paper, "The Wholeness Axiom",  found under title on the Web).  The definition is as follows:  "Suppose ($M$, $\in$) is a model of $ZF$ and $X$ $\subseteq$ $M$.  Then $X$ is _weakly definable_ in $M$ if the expanded model ($M$, $\in$, $X$) satisfies all instances of Replacement for formulas in the expanded language.  It is straightforward to show that whenever $X$ is definable in $M$, it also must be weakly definable in $M$."

Comment: (cont.)  If one substitutes $V$ for $M$ in the definition and $j$ for $X$ and one assumes $j$ satisfies the Wholeness Axiom, one can infer that $j$ is not definable in $V$ so $j$ is not first-order definable and therefore must be a proper class.

Comment: (cont.)  If one uses Prof. Goldberg's assertion that "$NGB$ proves that for all classes $C$ [including $j$--my comment], the first-order replacement schema holds relative to $C$ [and $j$ as well--my comment also], one can see that the last clause of the Wholeness Axiom, i.e., "that for all sets $A$, $j$ $\upharpoonright$ $A$ is a set" holds as well.

Comment: Why the downvote?